# In Raiden's source, why is a result of state transition called "iteration"?

Tags: raiden

Throughout the Raiden source code, the result of a state transition is called a `iteration` (for example
https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden/pull/4791#pullrequestreview-285494821 ).  Where does this word `iteration` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No particular reason, it was just the name chosen initially and it was not changed. For further discussion refer to: https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden/pull/266#discussion_r103815203

Comment: I see.  The type has been renamed to `TransitionResult` but many variable names remain the same.

Comment: Hehe nice work digging out the conversation for that one. We should also rename the variables.

Comment: Renaming to be kept track in: https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden/issues/4798